# Pass value to the static query in Golang

Tags: sql-server, go

I have SQL statement in my code like below - how can I pass the value for the `@date_of_birth` field?

```
 strQuery := "select * from dbo.student where dob > @date_of_birth"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
db.Exec("select * from dbo.student where dob > @?",date_of_birth)
```

**Updated** here is the golang documentation https://go.dev/doc/database/sql-injection